# For nested objects best way to create react components

Tags: reactjs

I have below json structure,

Form

- Name
- Display name
- Group : Array - Will contain multiple group elements

  - Group name
  - Group display name
  - Question : Array - Will contain multiple questions

    - Question name
    - Question order
    - Question type

I was thinking of creating below components,

1. Form Component : Iterate through groups and add FormGroup component
2. FormGroup component : Iterate through questions and add question component
3. Question component : Displaying the question details

Whenever any update is made to Question component I need to pass the value all over to form component. Is there any better way of handling such situations? I am new to react.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you handle the update if using redux you could bind each update to each component, or choose to update only the parent which will be cascading to childs.
Updating at the parent level seems fine to me, then sub-component will take care to update their own subcomponent and so on.